What is the term for PIE *eu > Proto-Balto-Slavic jau?
What is the term for PIE *eu > Proto-Balto-Slavic jau? Raising? Vowel breaking?

‘Breaking’ would be a likely term. I’m not aware of a term used specifically for this particular change.

are you asking about a sound change *eu > *jau? Typically this is indicated with an arrow rather than a slash
